# Including "projects" in Jest config causes several redundant runs of each test

Tags: jestjs

I am using Jest in a monorepo. I am using create-react-app and so am configuring with [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco). Below is the Jest section of my CRACO config. With `jestConfig.projects = ["<rootDir>/packages/*"];` commented out, each test runs once. But when it is un-commented, each test is run multiple times, making my Jest calls take a long time.

I'd like to be able to take advantage of parallelization with [projects](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig), which should make my tests run more quickly, not more slowly.

How can I prevent the redundant test runs and take advantage of parallelization?

```
  jest: {
    configure: (jestConfig, { env, paths, resolve, rootDir }) => {
      // jestConfig.projects = ["<rootDir>/packages/*"]; un-commenting causes each test to be run repeatedly
      jestConfig.roots = ["."];
      jestConfig.setupFiles = ["./jest.overrides.js"];
      jestConfig.setupFilesAfterEnv = ["./setupTests.js"];
      jestConfig.testMatch = [
        "<rootDir>/packages/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      ];
      return jestConfig;
    },
  },
```

Screenshot of test run with `projects` enabled:
[image]

Screenshot of test run with `projects` commented out:
[image]

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this for our jest config. What you want to do is move all of your configurations into project-specific config files.

Your top-level jest config will look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    projects: ['packages/first-package', 'packages/second-package', 'etc'],
}
```

Then each package would have its own `jest.config.js` file like:

```js
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ["../jest.overrides.js"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["../setupTests.js"],
    testMatch:["<rootDir>/packages/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
}
```

I don't know how you would set this up with CRACO.

If you have shared config for all of your packages/projects you could create a `jest.base.config.js` and require that into each of the package-specific jest configs.

The important thing is not having a `testMatch` field at the root level. Otherwise, jest will "discover" tests at both the root level and for each package/project.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I ran into the same thing, I had the following root `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    '<rootDir>/packages/**/jest.config.js',
  ]
}
```

In my `packages` directory, there are some top level packages, but also some that are inside a `client` or `server` domain directory, so I used the `**` to resolve this. However, this led to the projects within to be run 10 times.

If I change my `jest.config.js` to the following, they only run once:

```js
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    '<rootDir>/packages/*/jest.config.js',
    '<rootDir>/packages/*/*/jest.config.js',
  ]
}
```

Guess there's some bug in the glob used by Jest.